# Change link href onclick then run it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open a link to a new window without using `window.open()` from a link retrieving from an ajax call.

I have an hyperlink with `href="#"`. I want to change the href then go to a link from an ajax call when the user click on the link once.

**I am not trying to change the link after the event has been consumed.**

Here is my code:

```
<a href="#" id="preview-btn-link"><i class="fa fa-eye fa-2x" id="save-btn"></i></a>
<script>
                var lockLink = true;
                $("#preview-btn-link").click(function (e) {
                    if (lockLink) {
                        lockLink = false;
                        e.preventDefault();

                        var a = $(this);
                        saveProject("true", function (r) {
                            gvwcProject.id = r;

                            $.post("ajax_path", {"id": r, "pn": paj.non})
                                    .done(function (r) {
                                        console.log(r);
                                        a.attr("href", r);

                                        a.click();
                                    })
                                    .fail(function () {
                                        console.log("fail");
                                    });

                        }, function () {
                            console.log("failed");
                        });
                    } else {
                        lockLink = true;
                    }
                });
</script>
```

I can see the link from the href has been changed. But it does not call the link back even if I click on the link back.

Comment: Please share your html code as well to understand it better.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please clarify further.

Comment: I just edit the question.

Comment: To clarify: you want to send some data to the server and thereafter proceed to some other destination? Assuming that is the case, use a direct link to the server (or a form submission), and have the server redirect the user to the proper destination after the submission. There's no need for the JS to do anything fancy here.

Comment: The problem is. The client side I will post some data to the server. But these data is too long for a url schema.

Comment: Maybe I should use a form. I will try a with form and see if I can get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just get it work by submiting a form.

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="the_link" target="_blank">
  --some fields --
</form>
```

js:

```
$("#preview-btn-link").click(function (e) {
   //some check
   //Edit the form attributes then submit
   $("#form").submit();

   return false;
 });
```